# Minix print from kernel to console

Tags: printing, kernel, minix

I am trying to change the scheduling in Minix and want to print from /kernel/proc.c to standard output. Printf cannot be used inside kernel. I am using Minix 3.1.2.

I want to add code to

```
sched()
```

function in order to print messages to console.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Call `printk(const char *fmt, ...)`.

Comment: i have tried that and during kernel compilation it fails showing Undefined: _printk

Comment: printk was disabled as of minix 2.0.3.  Instead a file /usr/src/lib/libsys/kprintf.c redefines printf("text", ...) which should work from proc.c but doesn't.