# printf in C is printing the specifier to the console

Tags: c, printf, minix

I am trying to print some stats about the hole struct in MINIX 3 kernel, I have modified the file alloc.c to print the number of holes in the list, number of iterations before a hole in the list was found and average size of the holes. I use printf to print to the console but it keeps printing type specifiers to the console screen. Here is a piece of my code:

```
printf("Total number of holes: %i\n", numHoles);
```

the output is:

```
Total number of holes: %i
```

It is printing the specifier as if it didn't recognize the type specifier.
I declared numHoles as `int numHoles = 0;` and just incremented it in a loop structure. I have also added `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `%d` or `%u`?

Comment: Are you doing this in the MINIX kernel? `printf()` may not be available in the kernel, there's usually a simpler function.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @t0mm13b What exactly are you missing? The code, the output and the explanations are all there.

Comment: No, I have one other printf statement that prints the average that is a float value using the %f specifier and the same thing happens, %f literally gets printed to the screen. So I assume it's not the type being used that is the issue. But I'll try it anyway. @WilliamPursell

Comment: @GolezTrol the question is assuming that its a standard console stuff.. am surprised that the runtime is not specifying it, what command was used to compile/link, that's what I was referring to, a one liner does not just cut it.

Comment: `%f` isn't always implemented either. Try a basic test with `%d` and if necessary cast the value with `(int)`

Comment: @Barmar Yes it is in the kernel. What other functions exist?

Comment: Think you should amend your question to state that its a kernel code, printf would not be available, perhaps a more simpler printf without format specifiers? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847666/minix-print-from-kernel-to-console)

Comment: I don't know about MINIX specifically, but Unix kernels have [`printk()`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/how-exactly-does-printk-work-internally).